# Error bounds in representing a vector using a truncated Moore-Penrose biorthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, signal-processing, wavelets

I was reading and trying to reproduce the results in the arXiv preprint of [Periodic Gabor Functions with Biorthogonal Exchange: A Highly Accurate and Efficient Method for Signal Compression](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0632) by Asaf Shimshovitz et al., and a few questions arose. In brief, the paper outlines a new (as of 2012) family of wavelet-like expansions (closely related to the von Neumann lattice functions) which are time-frequency localized, and I have questions regarding how badly the method can fail when they're potentially used in signal compression or quantum-chemical calculations.

Most of the details of the paper can be stripped away to give a simple linear algebra procedure, as follows. Given a vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and a not necessarily linearly-independent basis $\mathbf{G}=\{\mathbf{g}_1,\mathbf{g}_2,...,\mathbf{g}_n\}$ of column vectors spanning $\mathbb{C}^n$, the following identity holds:
$$\mathbf{B}\mathbf{G}^\dagger \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$$
where $\mathbf{B}=(\mathbf{G}^\dagger)^{-1}$. In Dirac notation, this trivial statement reads as
$$\sum_{j=1}^n|\mathbf{b}_j\rangle\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_j|\mathbf{b}_j\rangle=|\mathbf{v}\rangle$$
which can be interpreted as saying that given any vector $\mathbf{v}$ and basis $\mathbf{G}$, the expansion coefficients $\beta_j$ of $\mathbf{v}$ in the basis $\mathbf{B}$ biorthogonal to $\mathbf{G}$ are simply given by the inner products $\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle$.

With a clever choice of $\mathbf{G}$, one often finds that the majority of the inner products $\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle$ nearly vanish, and one is naively tempted to approximate $\mathbf{v}$ as
$$|\mathbf{v}\rangle\approx\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ \langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle\geq\delta}}^n|\mathbf{b}_j\rangle\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle$$
where $\delta$ is some compression threshold. In matrix notation, this reads
$$\mathbf{v}\approx\mathbf{B}_{tr}(\mathbf{G}_{tr})^\dagger\mathbf{v}$$
where $\mathbf{G}_{tr}=\{\mathbf{g}_j|\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle\geq\delta\}$ is the basis $\mathbf{G}$ truncated to only include the basis columns which have considerable overlap with $\mathbf{v}$, and $\mathbf{B}_{tr}$ is the corresponding truncated version of $\mathbf{B}$.

This approximation is decent but not optimal; the optimal approximation is actually
$$\mathbf{v}\approx\mathbf{B}_{tr}'(\mathbf{G}_{tr})^\dagger\mathbf{v}$$
where $\mathbf{B}_{tr}'=(\mathbf{G}_{tr}^\dagger)^+$ where $+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse; a proof of optimality is simple and relies on basic facts about pseudoinverses, so I'll skip it. The use of $\mathbf{B}_{tr}'$ instead of $\mathbf{B}_{tr}$ is referred to as the Porat (Genossar) correction in the paper.

Simply put, my question is:

- Are there any reliable bounds on the error inherent in this approximation, given knowledge of the coefficients $\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle$ and the compression threshold $\delta$? For example, if we choose $\delta$ so that $\frac{\sum_{\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle\geq\delta}|\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle|^2}{\sum_{j=1}^n|\langle\mathbf{g}_j|\mathbf{v}\rangle|^2}=0.99$, can we say that the truncation-compressed vector is 99% close to the original? Or is it much worse than that? Or can we say nothing? If we can say nothing, is there any further info which would allow us to say something useful?

The paper gives no statements regarding error bounds, which I assume the authors had set aside for later to figure out; this is probably largely due to the fact that the original motivation for the von Neumann wavelet procedure was for quantum mechanical calculations, rather than signal compression applications. Nevertheless, knowing bounds on how reliable the technique is seems like an essential facet of any compression method. For now, let's assume that the basis vectors $\mathbf{g}_j$ of $\mathbf{G}$ are normalized to one ($\mathbf{g}_j^\dagger\mathbf{g}_j=1$). My first thoughts on attacking this were that the error can be quantified by the expression
$$\epsilon:=\frac{|\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{B}_{tr}'\mathbf{G}_{tr}^\dagger\mathbf{v}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^2}=\frac{|(I-\mathbf{A}^+\mathbf{A})\mathbf{v}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^2}=\frac{|P_{R(\mathbf{G}_{tr})}\mathbf{v}|^2}{|\mathbf{v}|^2}$$
where $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{G}_{tr}^\dagger$ and $P_{R(\mathbf{G}_{tr})}$ is the projector operator onto the subspace spanned by the columns of $\mathbf{G}_{tr}$. But I'm stuck here, and not sure where to go (I'm not particularly good at math). Does anyone have any helpful clues or intuition?

As an unrelated but interesting bit of visual imagery, here is a picture of the signal $\frac{k^2}{67108864}+\sin
   \left(\frac{k^3}{64000000}-\frac{k^2}{4900}+\frac{k}{4}\right) \cos
   \left(\frac{k}{3}\right)$ for $1\leq k\leq 16384$ in the von Neumann domain (brightness corresponds to absolute value of coefficient and color corresponds to phase angle in complex plane, with red being 1, green being $i$, cyan being -1, and purple being $-i$, with the time axis on bottom and the frequency axis on the side):

[image]